# On rendering PDF and modifying Uri

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to render PDF link using a webview. The link I am trying to render, is uploaded by my app to the firebase database.

While the link is rendered succesffuly on the iOS devices. It isn't on the Android.

I greatly speculate the reason behind all this confusion to be the firebase link .

If I try to render a normal pdf link from the web.

```
String pdf_sample = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
    String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";

    Webviewz.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Webviewz.loadUrl(googleDocs + pdf_sample);
```

Resulting in succesful PDF rendering

[image: image -SUCCESSSFULLY- displaying a normal PDF Url]

If however I rely and attempt to display and render a PDF link from my Firebase database, I get this blank dark gray background by google docs and a sign of **NO PREVIEW AVAILABLE**

```
    String Firebase_link_failure = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jouska-aabee.appspot.com/o/PDF_files%2F305?alt=media&token=b9cf2fa6-f6ff-4a3b-8908-9eac294c4668";
    String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";

    Webviewz.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Webviewz.loadUrl(googleDocs + Firebase_link_failure);
```

Resulting in **No Preview Available**

[image: image -FAILURE- displaying a Firebase PDF link on android devices]

> The solution suggested by the user **sphippen** worked out. Using the UrlEncoder on the firebase link, The pdf was successfully rendered. Below is the single modification made.

```
Webviewz.loadUrl(googleDocs+ URLEncoder.encode(firebase_link, "utf-8"));
```

Comment: When I try to use that link, it reports `The specified key does not exist.` So I don't see why you'd expect the app to behave differently? Also, where are you calling `storageRef.child("...").getDownloadUrl()` as directed in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)?

Comment: that's mostly due the fact I had removed the link earlier on, pardon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're just appending two strings to form your URL:

```
Webviewz.loadUrl(googleDocs + pdf_sample);
```

Looking at the full URL (using the values from your code sample):

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jouska-aabee.appspot.com/o/PDF_files%2F8828?alt=media&token=fab355da-47a6-4a27-894f-40798590a89a

The `&` character after `alt=media` ends the `url` parameter, so the URL the page tries to access is just https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jouska-aabee.appspot.com/o/PDF_files%2F8828?alt=media, which doesn't contain the download token.

**You'll need to escape the Firebase Storage download link for use as a URL parameter** (replacing `&` with `%26`, `?` with `%3F`, `%` with `%25`, etc.). The [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class should work:

```
URLEncoder.encode(pdf_sample, "UTF-8")
```